# How to plot the graph so that it doesn't touch the y-axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code and I would like to know what changes should I do so that the graph doesn't touch the y-axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    clip=false
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks,blue,line width=1pt,samples=150,domain=-0.1:6] {ln(x)};
    \node[right,black] at (axis cs:4.2,1.8) {\textbf{\textit{y = ln x}}};
    \node[below,black] at (axis cs:6,-0.1) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
    \node[black] at (axis cs:0.2,2) {\textbf{\textit{y}}};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by fend off?

Comment: Normally I am posting that for new guests on our site: "Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem."

Comment: To Fend = to Separate

Comment: Because the logarithmic functions converge asymptotically to the -yaxis, you cannot get a visual separation for the axis.  The rate of convergence to the y-axis is exponential so very quickly the difference between the y-axis and the ln(x) curve is less that a pixel with any output device.

Comment: R. Schumacher, You're right about the asymptotic point. I haven't forgot about this. But, I thought the chart to be shown could be from a height such that the part of the Y axis

Comment: Such that the part of the Y axis *what*?

Comment: So you want to separate the plot from the Y axis? As in, add some blank space?

Comment: Yes. I want to plot with some blank space between the curve and the Y axis

Comment: @benedito I took the liberty of editing the title and the body of your question, so it is clear for everyone. I hope it's OK with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code shows two possibilities: in both cases I changed the domain to `0.1:6` instead of your `-0.1:6` and then used `enlargelimits` (first example) and a value for `xmin` (second example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    enlarge x limits,
    clip=false
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks,blue,line width=1pt,samples=150,domain=0.1:6] {ln(x)};
    \node[right,black] at (axis cs:4.2,1.8) {$y = \ln x$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xmin=-0.1,
    clip=false
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks,blue,line width=1pt,samples=150,domain=0.1:6] {ln(x)};
    \node[right,black] at (axis cs:4.2,1.8) {$y = \ln x$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Remarks:

- The use of italics and boldface is not the best here; use math mode (and bold face, if really required).
- Yo get the appropriate font and spacing use `\ln` in math mode for the natural logarithm.
- Instead of manually placing the labels for the axis, I used the `xlabel`, `ylabel` keys,